# fmin python function with multiple arguments

Tags: python, scipy

I want to find the minimum of a function with 3 args but want to fix two and only vary one of them, e.g.,

```
def f(x, y, z):
    result =  f(x,y,z)
    return result
```

`y` and `z` are constants. `x` is the only parameter I want to vary.

optimize.fmin (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html) seems ideal for that, but the documentation is unclear on how to specify which parameters are constants and which are to be varied. Any hints on how to do it

Comment: Your code would lead to infinite recursion, and I'm not sure what you mean by "x is the parameter I want to vary". Can you clarify what exactly you're doing with `x`?

Comment: Say I know that x is within the range 0 and 1000 and, and for a given y and z, the function f(x,y,z) will produce a u-shaped function (x -axis is 0 to 1000). I want to find the value of x that gives me the 'result' whose value is the minimum. Note that f(x,y,z) is a generic function.

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html

Answer (score 1):

optimize always assumes the first argument is the one that varies, and remaining ones have to be fixed beforehand, either by creating partial function or by passing additional arguments as `args`, thus

```
print fmin(foo, x0=..., args={'y': ..., 'z': ...})
```